# How to dynamically add controls and preserve Viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, viewstate

I'm attempting to use `Controls.AddAt()`, but it apparently breaks controls at later indexes:

Here's my minimal example:

Aspx put in a form:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" />
<asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed2_Click" />
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ddl.Items.Add("Click the button")   
        'Controls.Add(New HyperLink) 'Works fine, but is put at end of collection.
        'Controls.AddAt(2 ,New HyperLink) 'Is also safe but I wanted the control first
        Controls.AddAt(0, New HyperLink) 'ddl loses it's item after postback
    End If
End Sub
```

On the first postback of the page after calling AddAt, the DropDownList loses it's item. It doesn't matter what kind of control I add even HTMLControls. Viewstate is not disabled.

How do I dynamically add controls without breaking others?

Comment: I know that I can safely add controls during the PreInit event, but my actual use case is adding them during a postback event. This is a minimalistic example of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a PlaceHolder to add your HyperLink into, it would not mess up the rest of the page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="bn1" Text="text" OnClick="Unnamed2_Click" runat="server" />
```

With code like

```
Protected Sub Unnamed2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bn1.Click
    Dim newItem = "Click the button" & DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
    ddl.Items.Add(newItem)
    ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.Count - 1
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New HyperLink With {.ID = "hyp", .Text = "Hyperlink here"})

End Sub
```

And always give your `asp:Control`s an ID if they take one.

Comment: While this technically answers my question (since I edited out the no placeholders comment), it doesn't address the actual issue. Requiring the insertion of the Placeholder at design time is specifically what I was attempting to avoid. I want to add the control at runtime at a position I choose at runtime.

Comment: @DanielCook I don't think that there is a good non-masochistic reason to try to fight against the way ASP.NET is designed to work. If you really want to, you could use something like jquery with AJAX to insert DOM elements, but then you're at one more level of complexity. I guess the whole page is too complex to render entirely by writing controls for *everything*, but perhaps there is just a part of it into which you want to add a Control and so you could create just that part programatically.

Comment: It appears that you are correct. I messed around a little more with my example and got this gem in an error message: "For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request" I'm tempted to delete the question, but I guess I'll give you a +1 for leading me to better understanding of why what I'm trying to do shouldn't work.

Comment: @DanielCook You might as well leave the question as it is so that others in the future can see that it is not such as good idea, and your error message quote is useful. The rep doesn't bother me: delete away if you think it is the best option.